# ASP.NET Core - JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition not working for IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json

I've one ASP.NET web app running over .NET Core 3.1 into one AWS Lambda;

On Startup.cs I had this configuration:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
{
    opt.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
});
```

After update the package "Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer" to the version "7.1.0", ASP.NET version and System.Text.Json was updated together.

Everything continues running ok, but the JsonSerializerOptions API changes and property "IgnoreNullValues" keeps obsolete. The link below suggests changes the configuration to use property "DefaultIgnoreCondition":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.ignorenullvalues?view=net-6.0

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
{
    opt.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

But after it, properties with type IEnumerable returns after serialization even when the property has a null value;

My question is: **How to keep the behavior to not include the property when is null, even to IEnumerable<> properties?**

I need don't change the behavior of the Web API consumed for some Delphi desktop app that breaks when receive null to lists.

Observation: I notice that the behavior occur in System.Text.Json from version 6.x.x

Comment: Can't reproduce with a simple test model, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rxcyny.  When I serialize the following model: `public class RootObject { public IEnumerable<string> IEnumerableProperty { get; set; } = null; }` with `DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull`, the result is `{}` -- i.e. `IEnumerableProperty` is skipped when null.  Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc Thanks for help ... I solve my problema backing version of the System.Text.Json to 5.x.x.
What the version have you used to test?

Comment: The fiddle shows *Environment version: .NET 6.0.0-rtm.21522.10 (6.0.0), System.Text.Json version: System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somebody can use the [repository](https://github.com/9b9/System.Text.Json_Ignore_Null_IEnumerable) to reproduce.

After my test, this scenario only happend on
**ASP.NET CORE 3.1** + **System.Text.Json 6** + **set DefaultIgnoreCondition** + **return ObjectResult()**.

And just like @Gean Ribeiro's talk, if you use [IgnoreNullValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.ignorenullvalues?view=net-6.0) and ignore the obsolete warning, everything can run ok.

Comment: ASP.NET CORE 3.1 + System.Text.Json 6 is a pretty unusual combination.  System.Text.Json 6 is designed to go with ASP.NET Core 6.  Not entirely surprising that `DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull` from 6 doesn't work in ASP.NET 3.1 since `JsonIgnoreCondition` didn't exist in 3.1.

Comment: Thanks for reproduction.
In my project I notice that the error was solved when I back the version of the System.Text.Json para a 5.x.x. But in the repository here, even when I back the version the error persists. It apper occur just with ASP.NET Core because in th @bnet reprodution, the error just happens with ObjectResult.

Comment: @dbc everythink work fine with version 6. I observe just the problem in this thread.